# using *. with arrays of arrays of arrays in groovy

Tags: arrays, groovy, syntax

```
[[1..4, 1..4, 1..4], [1..4, 1..4, 1..4]].size()  //return 2

[[1..4, 1..4, 1..4], [1..4, 1..4, 1..4]]*.size() //return [3,3]

???????????????????????????????????????????????? //return [[4, 4, 4], [4, 4, 4]]
```

Just wondering... It is possible to get `[[4, 4, 4], [4, 4, 4]]` through the `*.` syntax?

I tried `[[1..4, 1..4, 1..4], [1..4, 1..4, 1..4]]**.size()` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `[[1..4, 1..4, 1..4], [1..4, 1..4, 1..4]].collect { it*.size()​ }​` ... is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @dmahapatro Yeah but using the *. syntax. Well I don't need it I am just wondering if that is possible.